# Extracting values from a CSV-like file consisting of key=value pairs using SED

Tags: shell, sed

Input file:

```
Test1=169930;Testing2=240;Tester3=403;Tests4=RCFL2PKN;
```

Need to get output like:

```
169930;240;403;RCFL2PKN;
```

Tried to do it like this:

```
sed 's/(([A-Z][a-z]+)[=](^[0-9]+)[^;])//g'
```

didn't return any error, but nothing happened with output file.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/[^=]\+=\([^;]\+;\?\)/\1/g' file
```

In the [basic regular expression syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) you should write `\+`, `\(`, `\)`, and `\?` instead of `+`, `(`, `)`, and `?` correspondingly. If you find this syntax inconvenient, you may use the [extended syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-regexps.html):

```
sed -r 's/[^=]+=([^;]+;?)/\1/g' file
```

> The only difference between basic and extended regular expressions is in the behavior of a few characters: `?`, `+`, parentheses, and braces (`{}`)

If you want to modify the file in-place, use `-i` option. If you want to output the result into another file, use I/O redirection:

```
sed -r 's/[^=]+=([^;]+;?)/\1/g' file > outfile
```